# Trigger jQuery live search plugin with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I'm using the [jQuery live search plugin by Ryan Heath](http://rpheath.com/posts/413-searchbox-jquery-live-search-plugin) on my website. I added three checkboxes to allow users to check the things they want to search for. Now, I want the live search function to get triggered when a user clicks one of the checkboxes, but I have no idea how to do this with this plugin. I know how to bind stuff to a click with jquery, I just don't know how to trigger this plugin.

You can see the search function working on my site [here](http://ttrcustoms.us/#search).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **"checkboxChanged()"** function, call :

`$.searchbox.process($("#search").val());`

(I haven't tested it out, it's just based on the source of the plugin)

Comment: Tested on http://ttrcustoms.us/#search => This will work, if it's placed in checkboxChanged(). *upvote